# What is "voting bill"?

Tags: headlinese

the headline is:

"Florida senate passes voting bill to create election crimes agency"

when I google it it only return voting rights, I don't know if that is the same thing

Answer (score 1):

A bill is what becomes an act (or a law) once it is passed.

This particular bill is about the election process, hence a voting bill.

[Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese) often uses complex noun phrases whose meaning is not immediately clear, or may be confusing (sometimes called ["crash blossoms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity#In_headlines)). Usually the text of the article will express the matter more clearly.

Comment: I'm learning English through headlines it's pure head ache

Comment: I advise against this. As the article I linked to points out, they have a different grammar from normal English. They also sometimes use unusual words, or words in unusual senses (eg _bid_ for an attempt, _probe_ for any kind of investigation), and as you have found, they can be hard to understand.

Comment: @henrykearaudjo May I ask why you’re doing that? Why headlines, as opposed to books, or articles, or even movies?

Comment: @Annabeth Yeung, the answer to that is, when you learn by books or movies as you've suggested you get a big feeling of frustation when you come across a headline and don't get what is mesnt to say. its like all you've studied in books went in vain

Comment: @Colin Fine, I found that gem on crash blossoms: "French push bottles up German rear" but its said the author intention was: "that a French attack had choked German supply lines, that is, ‘push’ is a noun and ‘bottles’ is a verb." but how "German rear" refers to German supply lines? does rear has another definition than "back part"

Comment: @henrykearaudjo Please put those questions in a new question post.

Comment: @henrykearaudjo Again, headlines use their own shortened, dramatized form of English that should never be a priority for an ELL. If you haven’t mastered the rest of the language, you really shouldn’t be fixating on one niche corner of it.

Comment: No, _rear_ means "back part" - the part of the army that is not at the front, but behind, providing support. It's another instance of a headline using a short word in asense that is vaguely appropriate but which would not be used in that sense in other contexts.